# SSIS package script logging

Tags: sql-server-2008, scripting, logging, ssis

I am new to SSIS packages and I am trying to get logging to work from within a custom script. We have it logging the native messages from the package already but I want to add my own custom log messages to it. I see on the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponent` class there is a Log method but I am unsure what to use for the `dataCode` and `dataBytes` arguments so I used 0 and an empty array but this did not log anything.

So how do I get the logging to work from within my script?
Are there any configurations that I need to know about to enable it?

Thanks

Note: I am working with SqlServer 2008 SP2 (not R2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the task is enabled for logging.  Select SSIS > Logging... from the BIDS menu.  Select your data flow task.  On the Providers and Logs tab, ensure that a log provider is selected.  Select the Details tab and Check the ScriptComponentLogEntry event.  Note that this event is not inherited from the Package settings; so you have to select the data flow task.  Now your logging should be captured.

You may also be interested in the `ComponentMetaData.FireInformation` method to log an information event.  Here's more information on [FireInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337081%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) and related methods.  You may find these easier to configure, since the associated events (OnInformation for FireInformation) are inherited from the package settings.  In other words, if you set logging for the OnInformation event at the package level, all tasks will log the OnInformation event.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed that I forgot you had to be explicit about logging and that it didnt inherit. One curoius thing though is that `ComponentMetaData.FireInformation` logged the message twice  at two different levels. Perhaps it was becuase that inherited the config and I explcitly set it. Not concerned as I can just use the base class Log method call. Thanks